# file upload using Angularjs without backend script (eg. PHP, JAVA, etc )

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

As I am doing this just for demo, and my backend team yet not started, I want to save my file to the some folder of my project (**I don't want to save in database**).

I just want is when I am uploading some file and pressing upload button, that file should copy in perticular folder of project. These all should happend with AngularJS only or JavaScript. (**NO ANY BACKEND SCRIPT** eg. PHP, JAVA, etc)

I tried with these given codes, but it is not giving error **404: PATH NOT FOUND** for the folder to upload.

Tried Examples:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){

$scope.uploadFile = function(){
    var file = $scope.myFile;
    console.log('file is ' );
    console.dir(file);
    var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
    fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
};
```

}]);

https://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/

http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/1118/

Please, Give some suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In order to `POST` to a particular location, you need to have a backend endpoint listening to that location.  This is why you're getting a 404, not found.

The best you can do if you want to demonstrate locally is to make use of the `file.Copy()` method to simulate file saving.  http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0600__MS-JScript/FileCopy.htm

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for reply. But it is looking like copy the content of file to some existing file. I want to add new file itself.

Answer (score -1):

you can use angular-file-upload here [link](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)

Comment: In this also they are using php script. I don't want any server side script.